# Allow python script to be executed by Apache, but not read in a browser

Tags: python, php, apache, web

I have a website that uses a python script to get information from a separate entity. The python script is required due to the libraries in use and the structure of the other entity. The retrieved information will be used in various ways on the site.

The website itself is PHP running on Apache and there is a section that kicks off the python script. Obviously, being an Apache server, the python script is kicked off by Apache, so the script must be usable / readable by Apache.

The issue is that if a user goes to the location of the script (i.e. `www.mysite.com/scripts/myscript.py`), the code is viewable through the browser.

Is it possible to set up the permissions in such a way that Apache can continue to use the script, but when going to the script directly in a browser, the code cannot be viewed? I am also okay with changing the script to not be easily read (maybe obfuscate it?).

I have tried to change the `.htaccess` file to not allow the reading of files in that directory, but while it does direct to a 403 page when trying to view, it prevents the script from being used by Apache. I have also changed the permissions of the file to allow Apache to execute the file, but not read it... that seems to prevent Apache from reading the results from the script.

Any ideas?

---

Edit 1:
I think it should be noted that the python script is being kicked off by PHP through the exec command: `exec("$cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!;")`, where `$cmd` is the command to be executed. This may or may not be the best use case here. If there is another way to make PHP kick off a python script and get the results from the script, I am open to that alternative.

Comment: @esqew Thanks for the response. No, while that does prevent viewing of the code, it also prevents execution by Apache.

Comment: How specifically is the Python script being executed?  Why does it need to be in the web root and not simply anywhere else on the file system?

Comment: @David hmm.. you know, I think it could be else where on the system. I didn't think of that.

Comment: "*it also prevents execution by Apache*" It would be helpful for you to include the errors you're seeing in your server logs when trying to do this. I've personally never had an issue in this type of approach, so it's not clear what the issue actually is in your specific case.

Comment: @esqew When the script is kicked off from the page, a simple 403 is returned. Obviously, this is undesirable.

Comment: 403 is an HTTP status code - it's no longer clear to me *how* it is you're kicking off the Python script from your frontend through into the backend, but if you're using `exec()` your execution of the Python script is not being handled through an HTTP channel that would be capable of throwing such a return code. There is highly likely something else wrong with your architecture/Apache configuration that's causing this. Are you inadvertently restricting access to the PHP script that is itself executing the Python code you're mentioning?

Comment: @esqew I am not sure how to give you an error when I am not executing the script directly. I am not saying that there is nothing wrong with the code or architecture - I am not a perfect coder or human. But I am not sure how to show you all the code without giving you direct access. What I can do is tell you what is being seen by myself and users when I implement changes. I am going to try the suggest from David and see if that works. :)

Comment: @David That was the ticket. I should have thought of that sooner. Thank you for helping. If you submit an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-thinking it.  Note how you're invoking the Python script:

> the python script is being kicked off by PHP through the exec command: `exec("$cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!;")`, where `$cmd` is the command to be executed.

What *specifically* is `$cmd`?  The server can execute a script anywhere on the file system.  It doesn't need to be in the Apache web root, and indeed has nothing to do with Apache.

Simply put it somewhere else on the file system, outside of the website.

Comment: You're right. I was over thinking it... KISS, right? This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!